# No date/time shown before my page in Google search results

Tags: meta-tags, search-results

I know that by changing the meta description of my webpage, I can control the texts shown by Google in the search results.

However I do not know how I can control the text shown just before the search results, for example the date when the page was last updated. Which meta tag to use to accomplish this?

[image: How to control content of red squares]

**UPDATE:**
My webpage is automatically updated on a weekly basis on irregular intervals by a cronjob which makes changes to the MySQL database which holds the content of my webpages. So the question is what (meta) info to add to my page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data that you have highlighted in your screenshot of search results in known as [rich snippet data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en). By using [Schema markup](http://schema.org/), you can provide search engines with more information about the type of content your website contains.

You can see an example of the BlogPosting Schema markup that you'd need for this [here](http://www.ihid.co.uk/blog/markup-your-blog-using-schema-org).

As per your screenshot, you can also see what is required to mark job listings up using Scheme [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/JobPostingSchema).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the date then go webmaster and use data highlighter to tell search engines about the where you have mentioned the date.

Comment: This would be a manual action. Can this be automated?

Comment: This will be manual for just one page, Google will automatically trace the pattern and implement it for all pages.